# API стоит лимит, как избавится?

Tags: php, api

В API указан лимит, на вывод значений, если я ставлю лимит 999999 то просто белый экран, если не более 1000 такое происходит, ошибок никаких нету. Убираю из кода limit так же белый экран и ошибок так же нету. Не могу понять в чем может быть проблема. 
Вот части кода:

```
$videosdb = BiQuery1("*", "dle_site", array(array("news", 0, ">")), "news", "DESC", "{$news_limit}");
```

---

```
 function BiQuery1($sel, $table, $where = "", $order = "", $order1 = "", $limit = "")
{
    $query = "SELECT " . $sel . " FROM `" . $table . "` " . BiQueryWhere($where);
    if ($order !== "") {
        $query = $query . " ORDER by " . $order . " " . $order1 . " ";
    }
    if ($limit !== "") {
        $query = $query . " LIMIT " . $limit . "  ";
    }
    $query = $query . " ;";

    return BiQuery($query);
}
```

Comment: Посмотрите в лог веб-сервера. Возможно PHP тупо по памяти крашится

Comment: @rjhdby смотрел в логах, там нету ничего.
Память уже поставил 5000М

Comment: А ответ от API при 999999 - нормальный? Если да, то надо смотреть свой скрипт.

Comment: @IvanBolnikh нашел проблему, но не знаю как её разрешить. Выходит что когда выводятся русские символы сразу же белый экран. Выходит что если новость из таблицы взять с русскими символами, будет белый экран, если взять с английскими символами ту же статью, все работает нормально. Не знаю даже где в скрипте это править.

Comment: Надо дебажить скрипт. Возможно поможет просто включить сообщения об ошибках и тогда ошибка и где она произошла будет напечатана в выводе скрипта. Иначе можно разбрасывать `echo 1;` , `echo 2;` и т.д. по скрипту и так локализовать строку с ошибкой.